# boost::format with variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variadic-templates, boost-format

Suppose I have a `printf`-like function (used for logging) utilizing perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename... Arguments>
void awesome_printf(std::string const& fmt, Arguments&&... args)
{
    boost::format f(fmt);
    f % /* How to specify `args` here? */;
    BlackBoxLogFunction(boost::str(f).c_str());
}
```

*(I didn't compile this but my real function follows this guideline)*

How can I "unroll" the variadic argument into the boost::format variable `f`?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but have you tried e.g. `args...`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did try that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e651d5f7532cc67 , it doesn't work unfortunately (unless I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: That's how you expand variadic template arguments. Unfortunately Boost format uses overloaded `%` operator to separate arguments, which will not work with expanded argument packs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, it was designed before template parameter-packs and perfect forwarding existed, which accounts for a good part of the design (and its weak spots).

Comment: I suppose it could be done with the fold operators that come with C++1z. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold . Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582862/fold-expressions-with-arbitrary-callable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some googling and found an interesting solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

template<typename... Arguments>
void format_vargs(std::string const& fmt, Arguments&&... args)
{
    boost::format f(fmt);
    int unroll[] {0, (f % std::forward<Arguments>(args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(unroll);

    std::cout << boost::str(f);
}

int main()
{
    format_vargs("%s %d %d", "Test", 1, 2);
}
```

I don't know if this is a recommended solution but it seems to work. I don't like the hacky `static_cast` usage, which seems necessary to silence the unused variable warnings on GCC.

Comment: You can avoid the cast by not creating a temp variable `using unroll = int[]; unroll{0, (f % std::forward<Arguments>(args), 0)...};`

Comment: @Praetorian That works out nicely; however the `using` seems superfluous... I wonder why `int[] { /* ... */ };` doesn't work...

Comment: Because the grammar doesn't allow it. It's either the `using` or the cast.

Comment: Note that this trick is dependent on `f % x % y;` being equivalent to `f % x; f % y;`. (Also, I'd cast `f % std::forward<Arguments>(args)` to `void` just in case the type has an overloaded comma operator.)

Comment: You may also use `std::initializer_list<int>{(f% forward<Args>(args), 0)...};` to avoid the cast (and the case without args)(but requires an include).

Comment: Is `std::forward` needed in the expansion expression? What would be the difference between using it and specifying `args` directly?

Answer (score 14):

Just to summarize the [void.pointer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859893/5722863) and the hints proposed [by Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859672/boostformat-with-variadic-template-arguments/46123560#comment40465314_25859893), [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859856/5722863) and [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859672/boostformat-with-variadic-template-arguments/46123560#comment40469691_25859893), let me provide the final version ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d4795bba463338f))

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Arguments>
std::string FormatArgs(const std::string& fmt, const Arguments&... args)
{
    boost::format f(fmt);
    std::initializer_list<char> {(static_cast<void>(
        f % args
    ), char{}) ...};

    return boost::str(f);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << FormatArgs("no args\n"); // "no args"
    std::cout << FormatArgs("%s; %s; %s;\n", 123, 4.3, "foo"); // 123; 4.3; foo;
    std::cout << FormatArgs("%2% %1% %2%\n", 1, 12); // 12 1 12
}
```

Also, [as it was noted by T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859856/5722863), using the [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) syntax, available since C++17, the FormatArgs function can be rewritten in the more succinct way

```
template<typename... Arguments>
std::string FormatArgs(const std::string& fmt, const Arguments&... args)
{
    return boost::str((boost::format(fmt) % ... % args));
}
```

Comment: Wow, I love the fold expression... I didn't even know they added that. Awesome. Question for clarity: Is the inner parenthesis required in your fold expression solution? In other words, would this work: `boost::str(boost::format(fmt) % ... % args);`

Comment: I expanded your demo to include your fold expression solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfabe441fba08d62 I also tried removing those inner parenthesis but it doesn't compile. Would be educational to know why, though. The diagnostic doesn't help much.

Comment: @void.pointer, it seems that parenthesis around a fold expression is a mandatory part of it and can't be omitted. You can look at the [grammar description of fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) ("Explanation" section). When the fold expression expands, parenthesis around it are removed, so in case of boost::str((fold expr)), we need to have extra parenthesis to get boost::str(expanded fold expr) after the fold expression expands

Answer (score 12):

As is usual with variadic templates, you can use recursion:

```
std::string awesome_printf_helper(boost::format& f){
    return boost::str(f);
}

template<class T, class... Args>
std::string awesome_printf_helper(boost::format& f, T&& t, Args&&... args){
    return awesome_printf_helper(f % std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... Arguments>
void awesome_printf(std::string const& fmt, Arguments&&... args)
{
    boost::format f(fmt);

    auto result = awesome_printf_helper(f, std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);

    // call BlackBoxLogFunction with result as appropriate, e.g.
    std::cout << result;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdf228bf4621c004).

---

In C++17, simply `(f % ... % std::forward<Arguments>(args));` will do.

Comment: Forcing the newline at the end of the output is not a good idea for reusability: It's easily integrated into the format-string, and making it mandatory precludes extending the line *before* it ends.