# Fold expressions with arbitrary callable?

Tags: c++, fold, c++17

Looking over the C++17 [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html) on folds, (and on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)), I'm confused as to why the choice was made to only work with operators?  At first glance it seems like it would make it easier to expand `(... + args)` by just shoving a `+` token between the elements of `args`, but I'm unconvinced this is a great decision.

Why can't a binary lambda expression work just as well and follow the same expansion as the latter above?  It's jarring to me that a fold syntax would be added to a language without support for arbitrary callables, so does the syntax allow a way to use them that I'm just not seeing?

---

**Update:** This works for a variadic `min()` function with clang

```
template <typename T>
struct MinWrapper {
    const T& obj;
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename V=std::common_type_t<T,U>>
constexpr MinWrapper<V> operator%(
        const MinWrapper<T>& lhs, const MinWrapper<U>& rhs) {
    return {lhs.obj < rhs.obj ? lhs.obj : rhs.obj};
}


template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto min(Ts&&... args) {
    return (MinWrapper<Ts>{args} % ...).obj;
}
```

Comment: The main reason for fold expressions is for the use in concepts. "Normal" user code can already achieve all kinds of folding with ordinary library algorithms.

Comment: @KerrekSB One could still have a callable that uses concepts and does something other than apply an operator though

Comment: @KerrekSB: Could you elaborate on that, or link to someplace that does? I'm interested to see where this goes.

Comment: @Novelocrat: You'll find references in the intro of the Concepts TS, as well as in the cited N4191.

Comment: Good point. Write a paper.

Comment: Bah.  Now I need to figure out a way to get this to work with named operators.  Hmm.  May not be possible.  meh.

Comment: I think it is limited to operators to keep the proposal small. Also look at the limited list of ops that support an empty pack - I guess if you allow for arbitrary bin-fns, that whole thing would have to be expanded to handle that cleanly. That said, and in tune with your Q, I find the proposal rather terse, not to say half baked.

Comment: @Columbo [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/) is

Answer (score 5):

That's a great paper and a glorious language feature. If we bypass the standardese talk, which I'm not particularly fond of, I'd like to propose a **workaround**. Since I don't have a c++17 compiler (or a time machine) my answer will only be outlining, what I believe could be, a solution to providing **fold expressions with arbitrary functions** with the language status as is.

### 1. Define a type wrapper (a lightweight one)

```
template<typename T>
struct wp {
    T const& val; 
    // yes there should be constructors
};
```

### 2. Machinery to transform packs to wrapped packs

```
template<typename Op, typename Ts...>
using wrapped_pack = make_wrapped<Op, Ts..>
```

### 3. Overload a built in operator for `wp<T>`

```
template<typename T, typename U>
ret_val operator+(wp<T> const& lhs, wp<U> const& rhs) {...}
```

### 4. Use the wrapped pack in the fold expression

This would require an extra layer where the `args` of the fold are transformed to wrapped arguments

---

An obvious shortcoming of the above is that it doesn't guarantee uniqueness (or scalability) : every fold with a custom callable would consume a built in operator overloading.

There should be hacks to vary the types based on the expression they're encountered in but I don't want to dive that deep into a thought experiment (eg using the type of `Op` in the type of the wrapper already gives much more space to scale into).

Comment: `clang` current head from its svn repo has support for folds with `-std=c++1z`

Answer (score 5):

First of all I'm happy that what I wrote works in clang (I see your update implements 3 out of the 4 steps I mention). I have to **give credit to** [Nick Athanasiou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2567683/nikos-athanasiou) for this technique that discussed this with me way before writing [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/12/fun-with-folds-nick-athanasiou).

The reason I mention this now is because I was informed he released a [**library**](https://github.com/picanumber/reduce) (in the boost library [incubator](http://rrsd.com/blincubator.com/alphabetically/)) that implements this stuff; you can find **related documentation [here](http://picanumber.github.io/reduce/)**. It seems the initial idea (that we both use here) and allowed code like this:

```
(Op<Max>(args) + ...); // Op is a function producing the custom fold type
```

was left out in favor of lazy evaluation and stateful operators (or not included yet, can't know for sure).