# C++ fold expressions, how to apply it with a function instead of an operator?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I have a set of messages, some of which have variable sizes but still with fixed maximum sizes. I want to get the maximum size amongst that set of messages.

```
template< typename... Messages >
struct BinaryMessageList
{
    static constexpr size_t maxSize()
    {
        return (std::max(Messages::maxSize(), ...));
    }
};
```

So the point is to compute the same as `std::max(M1::sizeMax(), ..., Mn::sizeMax())`. I tried the multi arguments version of std::max or the usual binary version of std::max but I fail to compile that code. I know how to do so with operators but I'm unsure how it can be achieved through functions.

EDIT: I was redirected to [Fold expressions with arbitrary callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582862/fold-expressions-with-arbitrary-callable) but my question is not how to write a variadic max function but how to apply std::max to values of calls to variadic constexpr-ed Class::maxSize().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/max) has an overload that accepts an `initializer_list`, so you can:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename... Messages>
struct BinaryMessageList
{
    static constexpr size_t maxSize()
    {
        return std::max({size_t(Messages::maxSize())...});
    }
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!